# Two Layout in one Activity, searching for solution

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

**First** Basically I need to have  layout when application starts.
**Second** I am getting data from views i have in this layout.
**Third** Im setting next layout and doing hard code work with data, that I got in step 2.

I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Which step you can't figure out? All three? What you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use the framework class ViewAnimator without any animations.  It's not the prettiest solution, but should get the job done.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical">

  <ViewAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:id="@+id/viewFlipper" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    viewAnimator = (ViewAnimator)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    viewOne = createViewOne();
    viewTwo = createViewTwo();

    viewAnimator.addView(viewOne);
    viewAnimator.addView(viewTwo);
    ...
}

private void someMethod() {
    ... do my background task ...
    viewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(1);  // viewTwo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you gone through the [google notepad tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)? They explain using a list screen and loading a edit/add screen used to modify you sqlite database